# Sample OPC client with STA and MTA

Tags: com, opc, sta, mta, opc-da

Where to find the information about COM threading model used for the OPC client, as part of OPC lab certification process I have to verify that OPC client can be implemented using different COM threading models like Single Threaded Apartment (STA) and Multi-Threaded Apartment (MTA) should be able to connect to server and read data with out fail.

Used below client for testing but not sure what threading model the client was implemented with.

- Kepware- OPC Quick Client
- Softing-OPC Demo Client
- Indusoft-Webstudio
- Matrikon OPC Explorer
- OPCFoundation- Sample Client

Comment: If you do not find those information on Internet an alternative will be to send an email to each of them...

Answer (score 1):

When the COM client and COM server are in different processes, the threading model of the client's object does not "transfer" itself to the server, or have influence on the server side. The server controls the threading model for its own objects. See e.g. http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/apts/article.php/c5529/Understanding-COM-Apartments-Part-I.htm . The OPC cert process should recognize it, and apply only in in-process servers (which are, however, practically non-existent in OPC world).